# Graphics issues with live boot USB on Macbook Pro Retina

Tags: dual-boot, usb, live-usb, macbook-pro

I am exploring possibly dual booting Ubuntu alongside OSX. However, when I'm in the live USB mode, a lot of the dialogue options are missing and some icons will not open when clicked. Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

The live USB I'm using is of Ubuntu version 14.04.2. I am wondering if this is a resolution issue? If so, how can I fix it? My Macbook pro model is Early 2015, or 12,1.

Thanks

Comment: I asume you created the USB drive from the file ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso. Did you run and pass the "Check disc for defects" option when booting? What method did you use to create the USB drive?

Comment: I ran check disc for defects option and it says 1 error found but doesn't show me exactly where or what the error is. However, I tried booting off the same USB on a windows based laptop and it worked just fine. The method I  used to create said USB is detailed here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: If you use UNetbootin under OS X to transfer ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso to a USB flash drive, then "Check disc for defects" option will pass.

Comment: I used UNetbootin to make the flash drive and the check passed. However, the problem described previously still exists.

Comment: Also, I used the same USB on a 2014 macbook and it does not have this issue so I think it's specific to the 2015 macbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 1

I assume you are using rEFInd to bypass grub. One solution would be to add a manual entry to the `refind.conf` file. This will allow you to boot to grub from rEFInd. I assume you still have grub installed in your EFI partition. Add the following lines to the end of `refind.conf`. Reboot and look for "Boot Linux Ubuntu from EFI".

```
menuentry "Linux Ubuntu" {
        icon \System\Library\CoreServices\icons\os_ubuntu.png
        volume "EFI"
        loader \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
        graphics on
}
```

### Original Answer

This took about 5 minutes to figure out. Maybe it will help.

You state: My Macbook pro model is Early 2015, or 12,1.

That makes it a Macbook Pro 13" Early 2015;
Graphics and Video Support: Intel Iris Graphics 6100.

I did a Google search using: Intel Iris Graphics 6100 ubuntu

My third hit was: [Question #263770 : Questions : Ubuntu - Launchpad Answers](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/263770). Below is a copy of the given solution.

> > > Hey, I managed to find a solution for this problem, first I booted up into GRUB, (hold left shift after you turn the device on) went into advanced and selected Ubuntu recovery mode (second one down for me). Once it loaded up I hit resume and was able to access my desktop properly. I then went into the terminal (Ctrl +Alt + T) and entered exactly without quotations: "gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub". I navigated to the line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and modified it to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset". I then saved the file and exited gedit, I then entered another command without quotations: "sudo update-grub". I restarted my system and it worked. (source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

A better explanation of the changes are given at the source link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132. I included a copy below.

### How to permanently set kernel boot options on an installed OS (not wubi)

To permanently change the default kernel boot options, press ALT+F2 or open a terminal from system > accessories > terminal. Type in the following command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

a text editor will open with the grub configuration file. Near the top of that file you will see something very similar to this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

add your custom boot options to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line, so for instance:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Save the file and exit gedit. If you have to add kernel options that contain quotation marks, add them as such:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi=\"Linux\""
```

Now in the terminal, run the following command to update your grub configuration with the new default settings:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Thats all.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can confirm this fixes the graphical issue for the live boot. However, I can't boot into recovery mode after I have installed Ubuntu. I boot directly into Ubuntu using rEFInd. I have tried pressing F2 twice and typing in nomodeset in the boot options interface. However, I just get the same blank screens.

Comment: Also, changing /etc/default/grub didn't work. Is there a similar setting for rEFInd?

Comment: Tried [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/c30a6920/) and it didn't work either...

Comment: A added an Update 1. This should allow you to boot to recovery mode. First boot to rEFInd. Next select option to boot to grub. Finally, select option to boot to recovery mode.

Comment: @lpbug: Did you get it to work or did you just give up?

Comment: I got Ubuntu to install and created a file called refind_linux.conf under /boot with the nomodeset parameters then reinstalled refind with `sudo ./install.sh --alldrivers` and it worked.